# Sort arraylist based off time index JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sorting, arraylist

I have Python code written where a function gets in a JSON list (responses), a location (that is irrelevant at the moment) and a `tripIdArray` (an array with `trip_id` numbers that need to be compared with the `'responses'` list)
It returns a list where `'time'`, as a string, is the first element. I need to sort the list by `'time'`.

How can I do this? Here is my code.

```
def formMachine(responses, location, tripIdArray):
    predictionArray = []
    for response in tripIdArray:
        tripIdExists = False
        while (tripIdExists != True):
            for resp in responses:
                if (resp["trip_id"] == response):
                    predictionArray.append({'time': resp["arrival_time"],
                                            'location': location,
                                            'trans': 'sample data',
                                            'key': resp["trip_id"]})
                    tripIdExists = True
    return predictionArray
```

Time is formatted on a 24-hour clock (no am or pm), `"04:18:00"` for example.

Comment: `list.sort` and `sorted` take a `key` parameter which can be a function to extract the sort-relevant part (here the `'time'` value) out of the items to sort and to return it to the actual sorting function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: Thank you for the help in organizing my question.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
sortedPredictionArray = sorted(predictionArray, key=lambda d:d['time'])
```

This is because your array is an array of dictionaries. The `key` routine grabs a dictionary element to use for sorting.